# File.Exists returns false in one of many async tasks

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing some operation in many tasks. One part of Task needs to check existing of few files, and it's checking every file in another task, and after that if file exists, it loads that path of file to List.

My code gets link from database and deletes every sign from it to create name of file to find or download, if not exists. If code find it, then path of file is saved to table with proper index. And I'm really sure path don't contain nonlegal signs or path is invalid. Path is literally the same, like when it works.

Problem is, sometimes method `File.Exists` returns `false`. Of course file exists in location. It's not a permissions problem too, because other time that method returns true for exactly the same path.
Every task gets unique file to check too.

Code looks like this:

```cs
exists = File.Exists("directory/nameoffile.jpg");

if(exists)
{
  //do something
}
```

What could be problem? Too much File.Exists methods run in many tasks?

I'll add to it, that problem doesn't appear, when I'm doing it synchronously. Only when I'm using Tasks, I've that problem.

Comment: Please share exact file name and path.

Comment: Its very unlikely there is a bug in the BCL, which is what you are alluding to. This is most likely a logic problem in your code

Comment: Currently, there is too little details in your question even to speculate what goes wrong. One of my wild guesses is you are reusing the same variable in multiple threads, so it's changed between execution of File.Exists and if statement. Could you please provide more info on how your code works?

Comment: *The Exists method returns false if any error occurs* - from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists). Following [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,3360368484a9f131) it uses winapi [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) with all its limitations.

Comment: Though in short, if the file is there (no matter what thread you are on), it will say it is. you're problem is elsewhere

Comment: @So_oP For example: "directory/nameoffile.jpg". I'm sure it's proper path, because it's works in other launch of program with the same path.

Comment: Try to open it in Reading mode to catch the real filesystem error. Maybe a concurrency problem

Comment: @StasIvanov I'm using local variables for every Task (excluding table with results).
My code gets link from database and deletes every sign from it to create name of file to find or download, if not exists. If code find it, then path of file is saved to table with proper index.

And I'm really sure path don't contain nonlegal signs or path is invalid. Path is literally the same, like when it works.

Comment: `directory/nameoffile.jpg` is a relative path, use the actual path

Comment: @GhostVolume you should put those details in your question. It's a potential point of failure for sure.

Comment: @StasIvanov Good point.

Comment: Listen to the General. Use absolute paths. If the path is relative to app's location then construct absolute path based on that information.

Comment: @Dialecticus I'm testing that solution, I'll return with feedback and edit post.

Answer (score -1):

Skip then check and just start the operation you want to perform on the file and check the success or failure of the first thing (open/move/rename/whatever) you do. That's the "ok" you need.  In a concurrent situation, here one millisecond, gone the next (or vice versa) is par for the course.